# Why views is not identified when including it in an .ejs file?

Tags: node.js, header, ejs, footer, partials

This is my folder structure

[image: Folder Structure]

I have included my header.ejs and footer.ejs  file like this:
**<%  include views/partials/header %>**   and   **<%  include views/partials/footer %>**

but its showing me the following error:
**Error: Could not find the include file "views/partials/header"**

but when I write

**<%  include partials/header %>** and **<%  include partials/footer %>**

Its finding the file and everything works fine.

Also:
**<%  include /partials/header %>** is not working

What is the issue here and why?

Kindly share any  link/resource or any new concept regarding do this that
needs to be understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app.js` you might have this

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

So these lines set your `view engine` to `ejs` and also set your apps view folder to something like

```
/Users/Usama/Projects/YelpCamp/views
```

Now your app knows which is the views folder or from where to render views

So in any for your views files, you can directly use

> **<% include partials/header %> and <% include partials/footer %>**

no need for `/views/partials/footer` or if you add this Node.js looks for

```
/Users/Usama/Projects/YelpCamp/views/views/partials/footer
```

And this is why you get the error

> Error: Could not find the include file "views/partials/header"

And in the second case **<% include /partials/header %>** 
because of `/` it looks inside the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

In your first case `views/partials/header` just don’t use views as it's the default and in second case `/partials/header` it's looking from the root. So just use `partials/header`